# Overriding Tomcat's default error pages without web.xml

Tags: tomcat, jersey

My .war file uses Jersey 2.x and a javax.ws.rs.core.Application for configuration, with no web.xml file.

I want to turn off Tomcat's default error pages - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting the following property should stop error codes from resulting in an error page from the server

```java
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
        return props;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use Jersey specific classes, you can just use the string value of the constant

```
jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError
```

This is the javadoc for the propery

> Whenever response status is 4xx or 5xx it is possible to choose between `sendError` or `setStatus` on container specific `Response` implementation. E.g. on servlet container Jersey can call `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(...)` or `HttpServletResponse.sendError(...)`.
>
> Calling `sendError(...)` method usually resets entity, response headers and provide error page for specified status code (e.g. servlet `error-page` configuration). However if you want to post-process response (e.g. by servlet filter) the only way to do it is calling `setStatus(...)` on container Response object.
>
> If property value is `true` the method `Response.setStatus(...)` is used over default `Response.sendError(...)`.
>
> Type of the property value is `boolean`. The default value is `false`.
>
> The name of the configuration property is `"jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError"`.